# Python unit testing with VSCode behaves weird

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-unittest

I am using VSCode for my Python project. Unit testing (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing) works fine, but every time I execute a test (via panel or in code editor), the panel jumps from `Test Explorer` to `Explorer`.

[image]

This started a couple of days ago out of the blue. Any idea?

Comment: It sounds like it would be more appropriate to create an Issue under the [vscode GitHub project](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode)

Comment: Yes, probably. I just wanted to make sure I didn't miss any checkbox or anything. I don't know why this behaviour should be desired, but you can never be sure :).

Comment: I used my test example and didn't encounter the problem you said. Have you tried to update vscode and python extensions? If it cannot be solved, please submit GitHub